# Session timeout .Net MVC Web config does not work

Tags: session, iis, model-view-controller, timeout

I have set the web config session timeout to 480 minutes (8hours) I did the same in IIS for the app pool, then for the default website and for my website. Session still times out after 20 minutes, something must be overriding :/
Did anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had js script that waited for 20 minutes and then relocated the window to login page...
Obviously I changed the time to longer :)